# How do I test ASP pages locally on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, testing, asp-classic, localhost

Is it possible to test ASP websites locally on a Mac?

Comment: ASP Classic mostly. .NET on occasion. I'm new to Macs

Answer (score 5):

You could always run something like VirtualBox, and just run an instance of windows right on your mac.  Then you can just develop/test on windows when nescessary.

Answer (score 2):

For classic ASP there was a product called ChiliSoft ASP which allowed you to run ASP scripts on Unix servers. Unfortunately Sun bought the product and have now 'End of Lifed' it.

You could use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) to test and run ASP.NET pages.